# Example of merge operation in helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, sprig-template-functions

In offcial documentaion the description is very poor:

> Merge two or more dictionaries into one, giving precedence to the dest
> dictionary:
>
> $newdict := merge $dest $source1 $source2 This is a deep merge
> operation but not a deep copy operation. Nested objects that are
> merged are the same instance on both dicts. If you want a deep copy
> along with the merge, then use the deepCopy function along with
> merging...

Could you please provide example with input and output values ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider we have 3 maps (or Dict) as follows:

```py
dst = {
    "default": "default",
    "overwrite": "me",
    "key": "true"
}
src1 = {
    "overwrite": "overwritten",
    "key": "false",
    "name": "value1"
}
src2 = {
    "key": "false",
    "name": "value2"
}
```

You can represent it in helm with:

```golang
{{ $dst := dict "default" "default" "overwrite" "me" "key" "true"}}
{{ $src1 := dict "overwrite" "overwritten" "key" "false" "name" "value1"}}
{{ $src2 := dict  "key" "false" "name" "value2"}}
```

### Merge

In merging dicts, keys with different values will be kept, and in the same keys cases, `dst` dict takes precedence.
For example, result of `merge $dst $src1 $src2` would be:

```py
mergedDict = {
    "default": "default",
    "key": "true",
    "name": "value1",
    "overwrite": "me"
}
```

or in helm syntacs:

```golang
{{ $mergedDict := merge $dst $src1 $src2 }}
```

would be:

```
mergedDict: map[default:default key:true name:value1 overwrite:me]
```

### mergeOverwrite

In mergeOverwrite, precedence would be from right to left. So we have:

```golang
{{ $mergedDict := mergeOverwrite  $dst $src1 $src2}}
```

would be:

```
mergedDict: map[default:default key:false name:value2 overwrite:overwritten]
```

or

```py
{
    "default": "default",
    "key": "false",
    "name": "value2",
    "overwrite": "overwritten"
}
```

Comment: It should be in official documentation!